# I am not sure how to implement the Radio buttons and Check boxes as shown in image reference?

Tags: html, css

I am not sure how to implement the Radio buttons and Checkboxes like this: [image]

I have started to do it , but its not working on clicking radio button. please tell me how to implement these radio button and checkbox components .

```css
input[type=radio] {
  color: #6f7478;
  opacity: 0.6;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
}
input[type=radio]:checked {
  background: #0DFF92;
  border: 5px solid #0DFF92;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" value="" />
```

Comment: I put your code in jsfiddle and it is clickable. What do you mean when you say it is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. The button is clickable.

```
 <html>
     <style>  
        input[type=radio] {
        color: #6f7478;
        opacity:0.6;
        width:18px;
        height:18px;
        }
        input[type=radio]:checked {
        background: #0DFF92;
        border: 5px solid #0DFF92;
        }
    </style>

     Radio: <input type="radio" id="rd">
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below,

```css
.radio input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}
.radio span {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.radio span:hover {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.radio input:checked+span {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.radio input:checked+span:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid blue;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<label class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name='radioBtn' />
  <span>Radio button 1</span>
</label>
<label class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name='radioBtn' />
  <span>Radio button 2</span>
</label>
```